# ssh/terminal tricks with iPhone

Tags: iphone, terminal, jailbreak, ssh

I have a lovely jailbroken iPhone 4. Works fine. Very much enjoying being able to ssh into the device, but I can't help feeling I'm missing a few tricks with the ssh, would anyone be able to point me in the direction of where I might be able to do cool things? I'm interested to know if I can, for example:

Have the iPhone play music or make a noise via ssh command - would help when I know I've left it around the house somewhere...
Simulate a touch of the screen? (similar to, say, how Java's Robot package works on a desktop) Would be quite cool for executing macro commands...
Send an sms remotely (wishing now)
Any ideas? Anyone know if things like this are possible over ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from some general playing I've found the 'open' command on cydia, which let's you remotely open an app, not massively useful just yet. And I'm also using the 'speech' app that lets you trigger the speech synethsis from terminal - works over ssh and when phone is locked so quite useful for finding phone when lost in room somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

This will restart springboard:

```
killall -HUP SpringBoard
```

Not very useful unless you want to annoy your signifigant other.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remotely control the iPhone you should probably use vnc instead. Veency on a jailbroken phone will allow you to control the phone.